# Checking When animation stopped

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiimageview

I am working on a simple UIImageView animation. Basically I got a bunch of image numbers from 0-9 and I am animating them using this code.

```
myAnimation.animationImages = myArray;
myAnimation.animationDuration = 0.7;
myAnimation.animationRepeatCount = 12;
[myAnimation startAnimating];
```

Here myArray is an array of uiimages i.e. 0.png, 1.png etc.

All is well and its animating just fine. What I need to know is when do I know when the animation has stopped? I could use NSTimer but for that I need a stopwatch to check when the animation starts and stops. Is there a better approach, meaning is there a way I can find out when the UIImageView stopped animating?

I looked at this thread as reference.

[UIImageView startAnimating: How do you get it to stop on the last image in the series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351857/uiimageview-startanimating-how-do-you-get-it-to-stop-on-the-last-image-in-the-s)

Comment: It appears that you are doing a UIImageView animation not a UIView animation as you stated. So you're getting wrong answers for what you want. You should fix the question.

Comment: Correct Sorry about the typo in my question. Yes, I am animating UIImageView and not UIView. Can anyone correct the edit in my post -- Change UIView to UIImageView. I cannot edit the question anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the animationDidStopSelector. This will fire when the animation is done:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(someMethod:finished:context:)];
```

then implement the selector:

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSString*)animationID finished:(NSNumber*)finished context:(void*)context {

}
```

Comment: en.... should also add [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self] which I often forget, ha~

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for the answer but how do I tell which UIImageview it needs to check to see if it stopped animating? I wish I could modify the question above and change UIView to UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a much better approach than using NSTimers. If you're using iOS 4 or higher, it is better you start using block animations. try this

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:(your duration) delay:(your delay) options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

        // here you write the animations you want


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //anything that should happen after the animations are over


    }];
```

**Edit:** oops I think I read your question wrong. In the case of UIImageView animations, I can't think of a better way than using NSTimers or scheduled events

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my question. I wanted to ask how to check when UIImageView stops animating.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationDone) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```